# Get local IP address for socket

Tags: c#, sockets

I'm looking to get the local IP address of the socket I just created. I need to be able to support a server with more than one NIC and communicate back to the requesting client what the direct IP address is to connect later on. I'm using for following code:

```
Socket rsock = null;
rsock= new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetworkV6, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
rsock.SetSocketOption(SocketOptionLevel.IPv6, SocketOptionName.IPv6Only, 0);
rsock.Bind(new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.IPv6Any, port));
rsock.Listen((int)SocketOptionName.MaxConnections);
```

After this point, .LocalEndPoint kicks out: [::]:PORT.

**Background:**
The reason I need the IP address is that a secondary connection by another client will need to return to this specific server. These servers will likely be behind a load balancer for the initial server selection so the client cannot resolve the IP address based on the host name.

Comment: After you've accepted a connection from a client you should be able to use `LocalEndPoint` on the newly created `Socket` object to get the IP address you're looking for.

Comment: Even after accepting the connection via the following, .LocalEndPoint still says [::]:PORT.

`Socket nsock = rsock.Accept();`

Comment: You're saying `nsock.LocalEndPoint` still reports being bound to `IPv6Any`? I'm not in an IPv6 friendly LAN so I can't test specifically for that, but I _know_ this works for IPv4.

Answer (score 2):

Since you're binding to `IPAddress.IPv6Any`, the endpoint information will not be available before the first I/O operation occurs. The [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.socket.localendpoint.aspx) says:

> If you allow the system to assign your socket's local IP address and
>   port number, the `LocalEndPoint` property will be set after the first
>   I/O operation. For connection-oriented protocols, the first I/O
>   operation would be a call to the `Connect` or `Accept` method.

So, in your case, you will have to call `Accept()` before accessing `LocalEndPoint` in order to obtain meaningful information.

Comment: Even after accepting the connection via the following, .LocalEndPoint still says [::]:PORT. `Socket nsock = rsock.Accept();`

.LocakEndPoint on nsock says: [::1]:PORT.

Comment: How are you getting this information? Are you only issuing `LocalEndPoint.ToString()` or are you casting the returned `EndPoint` to an `IPEndPoint` and reading its `Address` property?

Comment: Correct, I'm casting to IPEndPoint and writing out the Address:
`((IPEndPoint)nsock.LocalEndPoint).Address.ToString()`

Comment: To close the loop: This was due to my testing environment. Since I was running this on localhost, I was getting my loopback NIC. Changing it over to resolve my computer name via DNS and this code started working. Thanks for the input.